# How to do data mapping with WCF and EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, wcf

My Question is about returning `EF` entity using `WCF service`. As `wcf` required Data Members for returning data. Solution i have to do mapping of entity to WCF `data members` which is quit hectic.
Is there possible solution which reduce my work effort. I tried [EntityFramework with WCF - how to return EF entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595544/entityframework-with-wcf-how-to-return-ef-entities) but available solution have support for vs2010
 only.

Comment: Automapper will help in this situation, or if you are doing code first you can just mark your entities as `[DataContract]`

Comment: can you please explain in details how can i do this.

Comment: You can look at the following post, might point you into the right direction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441325/how-to-expose-part-of-entity-as-datacontract

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky question. You want to pass EF entities through WCF. This is bad in some way, because EF objects are burdened with additional data provided by EF (e.g. for change tracking purposes). The best way to pass objects through domains in your application is create DTO objects. To do that, you can develop additional mappings (with usage of T4 templates) that create this DTOs based on your existing EF entities.

Comment: can you please share any example.

Comment: Unfortunelly no. This templates are generally specific for every task and I don't have any. The simplest way to do this is just copy edmx T4 Template and change few lines (change class name, add WCF attributes to class parts and so on)